# Can I use nuxt3 without router when I'm only generating one static page?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've noticed that in Nuxt 3 there is one `app.vue` file, and you can create a `./pages/index.vue` file, but if I'm only generating one static index page, can I just remove the vue-router and the `./pages/index.vue`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can keep your code in a single file as officially [stated here](https://nuxt.com/docs/migration/pages-and-layouts#pages).

> Nuxt 3 ships with an optional vue-router integration triggered by the existence of a pages/ directory in your source directory. If you only have a single page, you may consider instead moving it to app.vue for a lighter build.

You don't need to actually remove anything, if there is no `pages/` directory `vue-router` will not get imported in the bundle of your project.